# Scripted component placement in Altium

Tags: altium

I have a large number of components that need to be placed at specific positions. The Altium docs, and [this post](http://www.edaboard.com/showthread.php?t=180712&s=5d284803ac0b57a4794b85c4485904af&p=774186&viewfull=1#post774186) seem to suggest you can do this by going to `File->Assembly Outputs->Generate Pick and Place`, editing the coordinates in the generated file, and then going to `Tools->Component Placement->Place From File` and loading the edited file.

The pick and place file generator lets you generate it in two formats - CSV, and text. Text is just the CSV file laid out as an ASCII table.

I generated both files, and edited a few of the coordinates. The `Place From File` command expects a `.pik` file. I tried renaming both files to .pik and loading them.

The CSV file doesn't give any errors, but also doesn't move any of the components.

The text file gives an exception when parsing it (and actually deleted one of the components).

Does anyone have any idea how this is supposed to work?

Comment: Have you tried Altium support?

Comment: Yeah currently trying to negotiate AltiumLive... Just hoping someone here would know (and it helps future Googlers if the answer is here).

Comment: Altium does have scripts that you can do a lot with. An easier way would be to place the components and use the excel with pcb list to edit their properties, especially if you only need to do this once.

Comment: Depending on the number of compnents, paste array might work also

Comment: Would that work with components that aren't in a rectilinear grid?

Comment: I really so wish that Altium had used some common sense and gone for Python for their language. I cannot fathom why they would chose Delphi other than that they wanted to make it hard for people to switch in the future.